# Trouble displaying nested data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Been stuck for a while now trying to figure this out and pulling my hair out because it should be simple but I can't seem to get my head around how to properly implement it.

I'm using GatsbyJS with Contentful as a CMS.

I want to have a simple way for admins using Contentful to add new documents and for those documents to show up on the site under the sections (also added by the admin).

So essentially admins will see a section such as "**Minutes Documents**" and under that, they'd be able to add first a new **Year section** such as **2018** then under that section a corresponding document (link to PDF file) under the title of the **Month** that document was released such as **January**.

On the site, I'd like that to display like so for instance:

## Minutes Documents

### 2018

- Jan
- Feb

etc...

### 2017

- Jan
- Feb

etc...

So the admin can add as many **Year Sections** as they need and within that 12 files titled by Month.

The furthest I've managed to get so far is being able to display an array of all my documents added, but I can't yet get my head around how I can best split divide them up under section headers for each year.

**My current code is like so:**

GrahpQL document query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query NMODocs {
    allContentfulDocument {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          publishDate(formatString: "MMMM, YYYY")
          title
          file {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I have an array:

```
    <ul>
      {data.allContentfulDocument.edges.map(({ node }) => (
        <DocListing key={node.id} doc={node} />
      ))}
    </ul>
```

And a DocLising component:

```
import React from 'react';

const DocListing = ({ doc }) => (
  <li>
    <a title={doc.title} href={doc.file.file.url}>
      {doc.publishDate}
    </a>
  </li>
);

export default DocListing;
```

This currently results in a list of dates that link to corresponding document files. So to reiterate my question I'm wondering the best way to display this data under the relevant year section headings?

Apologies if this is poorly explained as I'm still learning and trying to get to grips with a lot of stuff that's new to me on this project. So I'm open to any suggestions or advice on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an array with accessible dates you could group them with a little helper function.

```
const list = ['2018-08-12', '2018-07-12', '2017-08-12'];

const groupedList = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const year = item.split('-')[0];

  if (!acc[year]) {
    acc[year] = []
  }

  acc[year].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Which would result in an object including keys for every year.

I'm not sure this possible with a GraphQL query.

Also in case you're relying on the publish date in contentful that's a little risky because I think it changes when content is updated to the last publish date (please double check). It might make sense to split it into its own content type so that you can set the date yourself and be sure.

Hope that helps. :)